# MySQL COUNT(), SUM() and GROUP BY

Tags: mysql

I have a particular question which is about MySQL. Please have a look at the query and the result set below:

```
SELECT COUNT(c.Population) AS c, c.City AS cc
FROM City c
GROUP BY c.City
ORDER BY c.City;
```

```
261 | Bristol
----------------
910 | London
----------------
241 | Manchester
----------------
```

I'd like to get the SUM of the COUNTs, so in this case I'd like to see '1412' in the next row, or in a new column, it doesn't really matter.

Any advice? I have tried to apply sub-queries to this but I couldn't find a proper solution.

Cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in the select statement, this should work (untested).

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(c.Population) AS c, 
    c.City AS cc, 
    (SELECT COUNT(c.Population) FROM City) as TotalPop 
FROM City c 
GROUP BY c.City 
ORDER BY c.City;
```

Answer (score 7):

Does [`WITH ROLLUP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-modifiers.html) do what you need?

```
SELECT 
      COUNT(c.Population) AS c, 
      c.City AS cc 
FROM City c 
GROUP BY c.City 
WITH ROLLUP;
```

Answer (score 0):

On one row at the end:

```
SELECT *
  FROM
(
    SELECT 0 as total
         , COUNT(c.Population) AS c
         , c.City AS cc
      FROM City c GROUP BY c.City

     union

    SELECT 1 as total
         , COUNT(c.Population) AS c
         , null AS cc
      FROM City
) myquery
ORDER BY total
       , city
```

ORDER BY c.City;

Answer (score 0):

With simple UNION;

```
select count(d.Population) as c, 'TOTAL' as cc from City d

union

SELECT COUNT(c.Population) AS c, c.City AS cc
FROM City c
GROUP BY c.City
ORDER BY c.City;
```

John